# eigen pair for sin(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np9C6.png)

I don't know how to get the eigen pair for $\sin (A)$

Comment: So if i get the eigen vectors of A i got the eigen vectors of sin(A)? No need to solve sin(A) after i get it the answer for A?

Comment: Yes. As $A$ is Hermitian, it has an eigenbasis. Hence the basis is also an eigenbasis for any primary matrix function $f$ of $A$, and each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ contributes to an eigenvalue $f(\lambda)$ of $f(A)$. You don't need to calculate $f(A)$ explicitly.

Comment: Just to clarify, how do you define $sin A$? Do you define it like $e^A$ is defined?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot i dont know how to upvote answers or mark it and for defining sinA i dont really know as we didnt take complex stuff such as the sines,cosines and exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's prove that** :Eigen pair of A and sin A are the same in the sense that if $(\lambda, v) $is an eigen pair of A then (sin$\lambda, v) $ is an eigen pair of sin A. $\tag{1}$ 
Since A is a symmetric matrix, it is diagonalizable that is there exist diagonal matrix D and orthogonal matrix Q such that $A= QDQ^T$ 
 Writing Taylor series for sin, we have :
sin A=$ A-A^3/3!+A^5/5!-...=QDQ^T-(QD^3Q^T)/3!+(QD^5Q^T)/5!-...=Q(D-D^3/3!+D^5/5!-...)Q^T=QEQ^T$
 where
$E=D-D^3/3!+D^5/5!-...$. Note that E is also a diagonal matrix with $\sin\lambda_i$ on diagonal. Columns of $Q$ (say $q_1,q_2,q_3$)are orthonormal(eigenvectors). 
Hence, (sin A)$ Q= QE\implies \sin A[q_1\; q_2 \;q_3]=[q_1\sin\lambda_1\;q_2\sin \lambda_2\;q_3\sin\lambda_3]$ By comparing columns on both sides, (1) follows.